# Handling 25,000 GET requests to an API

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, axios

So basically I'm trying to make a ton of, (about 25,000), GET requests to an API. I'm using axios as my library for making HTTP calls.

So I have:

```
dsHistPromises.push(axios.get(url))
```

And then I'm using:

```
axios.all(dsHistPromises)
    .then(function(results) {
      results.forEach(function(response){
        if (format === lists.formats.highlow) {
          storage.darkskyHistoryHighLow.push(requests.parseDarkskyHighLow(response, city))
        }
        // parse data here and print it to files...
      })
    }).catch(err => {
      throw err
    })
```

to handle all of my promises.

When I try to run my code, I get errors like

```
(node:10400) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: read ECONNRESET
```

I have to imagine this is an issue with the API I'm connecting to. The server probably is having a hard time managing my requests, correct?

Are there are any tricks to getting around this?

Comment: If you need to make that many requests you're probably doing something wrong. Also, the API is almost certainly rate limiting you here.

Comment: Nothing I can do I about the amount of calls. I'm calling a weather api, for 10 years of history data for several cities. Each day is its own request.

Comment: You're gonna have to slow down.

Comment: Sending 25,000 requests with no flood control to an API that is not yours is rude, and probably a violation of the TOS.  Are you paying for this at all?

Comment: Of course I'm paying for the rate the API Service is hosting the data for. I'm not an animal.

Comment: I think I know the exact API you're talking about. It has a way of getting that bulk data in one request.

Comment: Well, I say one. I think it's still paginated, but you can process it in chunks.

Answer (score 5):

As you suspect, I'd say it was because of the API you're accessing. Most sane APIs will have some sort of throttle to prevent one user from bringing them down. You're probably running into that.

What you'll need to do is throttle your messages by putting a time delay in between calls.

There are a couple of ways to handle this. One would be to do each call in order, one at a time. This will help avoid throttling from the server, but may be slower.

If the server will allow it, you can do multiple requests in parallel.

Basically, it'd look something like this:

```
const urls = getUrlsToCallFromSomewhere();
const delay = 500; // ms

const next = () => {
  if (!urls.length) {
    return; 
  }

  const url = urls.pop();
  axios.get(url).then(data => {
    results.push(data);
    const now = Date.now();

    if (now - start > delay) {
      next();
    } else {
      setTimeout(next, delay - (now - start));
    }
  });
};
```

This isn't super perfect, but should give you an idea. Basically, call them one at a time. When it's done, check how long it's been. If you've hit the `delay` amount already, call it right away. If not, use `setTimeout()` to wait the amount of time.

You can arrange your code to get a few of these going at the same time to speed things up, and adjust the delay to be as long or as fast as you need.